# Entity Framework 5 Code first custom key logic?

Tags: entity-framework-5

I have an entity (several, actually) that I want to have assigned a key value based on custom logic when they're created.  I know I could do it in the entity constructor, but ideally I'd like to do it as part of the data context logic for when a new entity is created.

I found how to turn off autogeneration, but what I'd rather do is replace auto generation w/ my own logic, ideally handled by the C# code (I"ve seen techniques for doing it via stored procs also, that I'd rather not use).

Is this even possible to do centrally?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Autogeneration happens on the server side and is not done by the EF. This is a setting on a table key column. So EF does not generate any keys - if autogeneration is turned on this is the database that generates keys, if autogeneration is off this is the user that is responsible for generating keys. If you don't want to generate keys when saving changes you may want to override SaveChanges and generate keys for all newly added entities.

Comment: So, I knew that their autogeneration is handled by the db, but my apparently erroneous thinking was that I could inject my own logic at that step w/o hitting the db (since there is still EF code running at that time).  I guess I'll do it w/ SaveChanges or in the entity's constructor.

Comment: There is ObjectContext.SavingChanges event you could also use but to me overriding SaveChanges here seems to be much cleaner. Note that if you want to create keys on your own you need to make sure that the keys are unique across or instances of your app and they don't exist in the database. This is why having the database create keys is so convenient.

Comment: Yes, I'm aware of that.  I plan on using one of the well documented ordered Guid algorithms, which should be unique enough for my use case.